# UIScrollView with multiple subViews

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with many other subviews inside it. Most of the subviews are `UITextView`'s and when they are all loaded, the scrolling and everything is fine. But for one of the views, I am loading a `UIView` with a `MKMapView` and a `UITextView` inside of it. When the user wants to scroll the `UIScrollView`, they cannot touch the `UIView` or its contents. I cannot set `setUserInteractionEnabled` to NO because I need the user to be able to click on the `MKMapView` and then go to another `UIViewController` for the map. Are there any suggestions regarding this? I have my code for the above below:

```
    CGRect dealDescRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, delegate.scrollView.frame.size.width - 22 - 20, 120);
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:dealDescRect];
    mapView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;

    BOOL result = [self loadAddressIntoMap];
    if (result == TRUE) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [mapView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }

    UITextView *addressTextView = [self generateTextView:addressText :5];
    addressTextView.editable = NO;
    [addressTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
    [addressTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    CGRect addressTextViewFrame = addressTextView.frame;
    addressTextViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
    addressTextViewFrame.origin.y = 130;
    addressTextViewFrame.size.height = addressTextView.contentSize.height + 15;
    addressTextView.frame = addressTextViewFrame;

    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 145, delegate.scrollView.frame.size.width - 22, addressTextView.contentSize.height + 135);
    viewRect.origin.x = 11;
    viewRect.origin.y = startTop;
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [view addSubview:mapView];
    [view addSubview:addressTextView];
```

**EDIT**

For some weird reason, if I change the `UIView` to a `UITextView`, it works! Not sure what the real solution here is though. I just disable editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, instead of using gesture recognizers to watch for a tap on the map I'd create a UIButton of a custom type (UIButtonTypeCustom) and give it no background and no text, and place it on top of the map with the same frame as the map.

This has the benefit of preventing the user from interacting with the map, moving to the next page as you want and if the user starts scrolling even when over the map they are able to.

Comment: That won't work as there is some text below the map (the address), and event that is part of the same `UIView` and will block touches. For some weird reason, if I make the `UIView` a `UITextView` and just disable selecting, editing all that, it works! Not sure what the real solution is though.

Comment: @KVISH Hmm. I may not be understanding the exact problem then. Which UIView are you making into a UITextView?

Comment: Look 5 lines up from the bottom.

Comment: @KVISH I'm not sure what to tell you. I just recreated your code in a project (filling in the gaps from code not posted) and it works like I'd expect. I can scroll anywhere and when I tap on the map it handles the tap as it should. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Perhaps i'm explaining it wrong. It's not the tap that doesn't work. It's when the user is scrolling the `UIScrollView` and when they try to scroll it by touching the `UIView` that I mentioned above, the touch events are not being translated to teh `UIScrollView`.

Comment: But the user is always able to tap the `UIView` and show the map that I want it to show.

Comment: Well, that's what I was assuming the problem was so at least I was on the right track. However, I am not having that problem in the test app I built from your code. When I try to scroll starting by touching inside or outside of the map I am able to scroll as expected.

Comment: Interesting...that's really weird. I'm never able to accomplish that with my previous code...